# Array HashMap - Basic Manipulation

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on a piece of work and have hit a brick wall. I'm really struggling to understand how to tackle the questions.

The basic code I've been given is a constructor for a HashMap. It's using string data types for both the key and value and storing them in an array. The code looks like this:

Note: I cannot use any packages.

```
    public class HashMap 
    {
      private long noofitems;   
      private HashPair[] data; 

      public HashMap(int initlen)
      {
        noofitems=0;
        data=new HashPair[initlen];
      }

      public void AddItem(String key, String value)
      {

      }

      public String GetValue(String key)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

There's also a second file which is for the HashPair, which is used to store the values.

```
        public class HashPair 
    {
      public String key, value;

      public HashPair(String key, String value)
      {
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
      }

      public String GetKey()
      {
        return key;
      }

      public String GetValue()
      {
        return value;
      }
```

Please could somebody give me some directions as to where to start with the AddItem function? I'm genuinely at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

First of all your code is missing ending bracket `HashPair`class. you need to instantiate `HashPair` and put it in `data` array i.e

```
  private long noofitems;   
  public HashPair[] data;
  int counter = 0;

  public HashMap(int initlen)
  {
    noofitems = initlen;
    data=new HashPair[initlen];
  }

  public void AddItem(String key, String value)
  {
      HashPair item = new HashPair(key, value);
      if(counter< noofitems )
      {
          data[counter] = item;
          counter++;
      }

  }
```

but you need more checks and functionality on data while adding items. Like you need to check what position to insert item and to check if your data is already full with given no of items

Comment: Not necessary, there is System.arraycopy for that.

Comment: Also, you need to use constructor parameter to initialize the length of `data `array by setting `noofitems = initlen `. You can use a counter to keep checking the no of items in your data array by incrementing the counter each time you add item and stop adding items when counter is equal the no of items.

Comment: Which part of this code has *anything* to do with hashing?

Comment: which part the user is concerned with hashing? The user needed a simple implementation to an item with the limited structure on HashPair

Comment: The part where the class is named `HashMap`, implying that it is an implementation of a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), same as the [`java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class in the JDK. If it's not going to do any hashing, why would it be named `HashMap`?

Comment: I think you are assuming too much just because its named as HashMap. If he needed hashing functionality as well, he could have asked. What you think a newbie can implement a perfect HashMap without being told about it. I believe it was just simple task to create Key Value pair data structure without hashing and all other details.

Comment: That is more of an assumption on your part, that OP hasn't learned about hashing, than on my part, that a class called `HashMap` should use hashing. If the `GetValue()` method is just supposed to do sequential searching of an array, then it should be named something like `ArrayMap`. Sure, we can assume that the teacher is stupid (indicated by violating Java naming conventions), but it's more likely that the student is not applying what has been learned (how hashing works). Of course, we can't know, since OP hasn't said anything.

Answer (score -2):

Here it is:

```
    public void AddItem(String key, String value)
    {
        HashPair[] tmpData = new HashPair[this.data.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(this.data, 0, tmpData, 0, this.data.length);
        // set new last elements data
        tmpData[tmpData.length - 1] = new HashPair(key, value);        
        // replace data with newly created tmpData array
        this.data = tmpData;
    }
```

P.S. IMHO: idea to backing HashMap with Array can come only into some academic/professor's head. :-)

Comment: You totally missed the fact that the array is the hash-table. Your code just appends to the end of the array, so 1) what do you think `new HashPair[initlen]` is doing, and 2) which part of your code has *anything* to do with hashing?

Comment: Did you read a question? It is "theoretical" attempt to make "kind of map" backed with Array as a storage. There is nothing about hash. Also what did you mean "array is the hash-table"?

Comment: BTW: it is not a full solution... it is a hint to think how array can be used as a table...

Comment: *"There is nothing about hash"* No? What about the *name* **`HashMap`**? Do you understand what that is? To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table): *A hash table uses a hash function to compute an **index into an array** of buckets or slots*. Keywords fitting question code: "HASH", "ARRAY".

Comment: If I see a horse and somebody tell me that it is a cow, should I do not trust my eyes?  Man if you'd like to look smartest in the world it is your problem.

Comment: If I see a horse (aka `HashMap`) and it has 4 legs (aka array for hash buckets), and someone tries to make it walk like a duck (aka make it behave like an `ArrayList`), then I'll call them out on it. I don't think that'll make me look the smartest in the world, it probably says more about the person trying to make a duck out of a horse.

Comment: Nothing to talk about... GTH